# addthis_widget detected as virus

Tags: malware, anti-virus

We use sunbelts VIPRE enterprise systems, and I was alerted to almost every computer in the company having this and being quarantined.

Is anyone familiar with addthis_widget.js. It detects it as a `trojan.js.redirector.bg` , I'm not sure if this is a false positive or if it is actually a threat.

I tried googling it a few different ways but didnt find anything definitive. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: +1 -We are having the same issue here.

Comment: yeah i started getting emails on my phone roughly starting at 7am this morning with high risk alerts so i got to come in nice and early :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a false positive.  I just found this on the GFI community site:

> We disabled this threat late last night to allow for further investigation. Please make sure you have the latest definitions.
>   Joe Frederick 
>   QA Engineer 
>   Sunbelt Software

Comment: i'm still going to quarantine it and then delete it. i dont know what it is so it is better safe than sorry

Comment: @Aaaron http://malwaresurvival.net/tag/trojan-buzus/page/2/

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same thing, 18 computers showing various threats. 
addthis_widget.js, common.js, friendconnect.js, espn.core.min.js and a couple others.  Seems to me there is something in the java script being falsely reported.

Comment: http://malwaresurvival.net/tag/trojan-buzus/page/2/  i do not know if this will help